# formula to search one field and generate outcome for another field

Tags: ms-access, excel-2013, ms-access-2013

I am trying to create a new field in access that is contingent on another field's content. For example, Field 1 contains the title of books, and I want field 2 to contain a 1 (or yes) if a certain word (out of a string) is found in field 1 (title). For example: (If Field 1 contains "gang", then field 2= 1, else 0).

I was able to write this into an excel table as : `=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("gang",D2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("gangs",D2))),1,0)`.I know I could import that table back into Excel, but much of my formatting is lost and any updates or new formulas would be tedious

Is there a way to create a new field in access that mirrors this formula?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write formulas directly to the cells in Access, as you did in Excel. But You can write SQL Commands to achieve it. I am not sure about the syntax now, but in SQL Server the syntax will be as following..

```
UPDATE YourTableName SET FieldName = 1 where CHARINDEX('gang',FieldToBeSearched) > 0
```

Comment: I believe in Access, this would be written as instr(Field, 'gang')

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you need with a field expression in a query.

```
SELECT
    Field1,
    IIf(InStr(1,[Field1],'gang',1),1,0) AS Field2
FROM YourTable;
```

With that approach, `Field2` would not exist in the table.  Instead, you would use the query when you want to see `Field2`.  And that means you avoid the need to revise `Field2` values when `Field1` values change.

However, if you need `Field2` to be an actual field and your Access 2013 db is ACCDB format, you can make it a calculated field.

[image: Calculated Field expression]